# refresh page using ajax with Jquery validator

Tags: jquery, validation

My page keeps refreshing after it comes back with data. I have used return false in submit handler but it does not working. I have tried to pass **e.preventDefault()** inside submit handler no effect.

```js
$('#submit').on('click', () => {
 console.log('hello');
 let x = $("#form").validate({
  rules: {
   title: {
    required: true
   },
   fname: {
    required: true
   },
   sname: {
    required: true
   },
   sub: {
    required: true
   },
   msg: {
    required: true
   },
   email: {
    required: true,
    email: true
   }
  },
  submitHandler: function (form) {
   $.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?page=contact',
    type: form.method,
    data: $(form).serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
     console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
     console.log(data);
    }
   });
   return false; // kill page refresh
  }
 })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" method='post' action="">
   <fieldset>
      <div class="form-row">
         <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label for="title">Title:</label>
            <select name="title" class="custom-select" id="title" required>
               <option
                  value="NULL" selected="selected">Please select</option>
               <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
               <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
               <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
               <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-5">
            <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your First Name" name="fname" id="fname" required>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-5">
            <label for="sname">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Last Name" name="sname" id="sname" required>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
         <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your full email address" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="sub">Subject:</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sub" id="sub" placeholder="Subject" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="msg">Message:</label>
         <textarea placeholder="Type your message here..." class="form-control" name="msg" id="msg" required></textarea>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

**php code**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

echo 'yes';
die();
}
```

I have tried to give on different event such $('body').on( ...) or .submit(..) etc
did not work
basically still refresh the page. 
If I change the input type=button then it did not refresh the page but then validator did not work and all fields have not been validated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `preventDefault();` in the top level of the click function rather than in the `submitHandler` function:

```js
$('#submit').on('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#form').submit();
    console.log('Form submitted');
})

$("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        title: {
            required: true
        },
        fname: {
            required: true
        },
        sname: {
            required: true
        },
        sub: {
            required: true
        },
        msg: {
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      console.log('Form is valid');
      $.ajax({
          url: 'index.php?page=contact',
          type: form.method,
          data: $(form).serialize(),
          success: function(data) {
              console.log(data);
          },
          error: function(data) {
              console.log(data);
          }
      });
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.1/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" method='post' action="">
   <fieldset>
      <div class="form-row">
         <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label for="title">Title:</label>
            <select name="title" class="custom-select" id="title" required>
               <option
                  value="NULL" selected="selected">Please select</option>
               <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
               <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
               <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
               <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-5">
            <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your First Name" name="fname" id="fname" required>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-5">
            <label for="sname">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Last Name" name="sname" id="sname" required>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
         <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your full email address" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="sub">Subject:</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sub" id="sub" placeholder="Subject" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="msg">Message:</label>
         <textarea placeholder="Type your message here..." class="form-control" name="msg" id="msg" required></textarea>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

Here's another solution that is more in line with what you were trying. The `validate` function gets called on submit of the form by default, so there's no need to wrap it in a `click` function:

```js
$("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        title: {
            required: true
        },
        fname: {
            required: true
        },
        sname: {
            required: true
        },
        sub: {
            required: true
        },
        msg: {
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      console.log('Form is valid');
      $.ajax({
          url: 'index.php?page=contact',
          type: form.method,
          data: $(form).serialize(),
          success: function(data) {
              console.log(data);
          },
          error: function(data) {
              console.log(data);
          }
      });
      return false;
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.1/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" method='post' action="">
   <fieldset>
      <div class="form-row">
         <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label for="title">Title:</label>
            <select name="title" class="custom-select" id="title" required>
               <option
                  value="NULL" selected="selected">Please select</option>
               <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
               <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
               <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
               <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-5">
            <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your First Name" name="fname" id="fname" required>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-5">
            <label for="sname">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Last Name" name="sname" id="sname" required>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
         <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your full email address" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="sub">Subject:</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sub" id="sub" placeholder="Subject" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="msg">Message:</label>
         <textarea placeholder="Type your message here..." class="form-control" name="msg" id="msg" required></textarea>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: That does not work because it wont validate the form I have tried that before

Comment: Please take a look at my update. First you prevent the default behavior on click of the button and submit the form which will trigger the `validate` function. Once the form is determined to be valid, it will step into the `submitHandler` function.

Comment: I see that worked but even in my first post it should work as I do telling the Handler return false. So why it did not worked?

Comment: It's because of the way you're initiating the validation function. In your code `return false` does not prevent the default behavior of the `click` event on the submit button. I have updated my answer with an alternative method using `return false;` If all you're going to be using the submit button for is to submit the form, then there's no need to wrap `validate` inside of a click function.

Comment: ahh I see I thought It would be nice to have actually click event on that form. Anyway Thanks it helps a lot.